# New Notebook, cannot find wlan drivers

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, acer

I have got a new Notebook, an Acer Aspire E5-574G-57ZD.

I want to install Ubuntu on it, 14.04 or above.

Apparently the notebook it has not been out for more than 6 weeks, and I cannot find the drivers for WIFI anywhere.

Does anyone already have them and could help me out?

Comment: What is the wifi card?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I am sorry, where should I get the output? just type it into a shell of a bootable stick of a linux distribution?

Comment: @user1862770 yes, boot up Ubuntu Live USB, select "Try Ubuntu without installing" , when you get to desktop, open terminal and run that command.   You can then use mouse/ touchpad to select the output and copy it here or paste to paste.ubuntu.com, and copy the link of your paste here

Comment: Likely WLAN chipset: **Qualcomm (Atheros) QCA9377 802.11a/b/g/n/ac**

Comment: Try this query: **`dmesg | grep -e Qualcomm -e Atheros -e WiFi -e QCA -e qca`** (*and report response*)

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow it is to late now - but copy paste won't work, if I had internet on that computer I would not need to post here

Comment: The only difficult character is the **`|`**, which is usually shift-backslash (above Enter key).

Comment: I tried the query that was suggested. There was no output/response. I am no further then I was, ubuntu is working fine, but no wlan. Is it really possible that no solution is out yet for this computer?